# Поменять местами 2 блока при изменении экрана

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Как поменять местами 2 блока которые находятся в разных местах кода если, размер экрана достигает определенной ширины и обратно когда ширина больше?

**Первый способ:**

```
jQuery.fn.swap = function(b) {
        b = jQuery(b)[0];
        var a = this[0],
            a2 = a.cloneNode(true),
            b2 = b.cloneNode(true),
            stack = this;

        a.parentNode.replaceChild(b2, a);
        b.parentNode.replaceChild(a2, b);

        stack[0] = a2;
        return this.pushStack( stack );
    }; 
$(window).resize(function() {  
if ($(window).width() <= '800') {  
 $('.first').swap('.second');
}   
});
```

Но при таком способе функция вызывается каждый раз когда меняется экран, к тому же в одном из блоком подключена яндекс карта и после перемещения она перестает работать.

**Второй способ:**

```
    var first = $('.first');
    var second = $('.second');

    $(window).resize(function() {


        if ($(window).width() <= '800'){
                first.detach().prependTo(second);
                second.detach().prependTo(first);
        };
    });
```

При таком способе консоль выдает ошибку:

> Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The new child element
>   contains the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(function() {
    var first = $(".first");
    var second = $(".second");
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var i = $(".first, .second").index(first);
        if ($(window).width() <= "800" && !i) {
            var a = $("<abracadabra/>");
            a.insertAfter(first);
            first.insertAfter(second);
            second.insertAfter(a);
            a.remove()
        } else if ($(window).width() > "800" && i) {
            var a = $("<abracadabra/>");
            a.insertAfter(first);
            first.insertAfter(second);
            second.insertAfter(a);
            a.remove()
        }
    }).resize()
});
```

Comment: Спасибо вам, добрый человек

Answer (score 0):

В этом случае так сильно напрашиваются media-querries, что я бы, если бы мне не подошло абсолютное позиционирование, наверное бы просто создал два экземпляра каждого блока и менял бы их видимость через css свойство display

```
<style>
.first {
  display: block;
}
.first800 {
  display: none;
}
.second{
  display: block;
}
.second800 {
  display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .first {
    display: none;
  }
  .first800 {
    display: block;
  }
  .second{
    display: none;
  }
  .second800 {
    display: block;
  }
}
</style>
```